# Meteor onConnection client side hook?

Tags: javascript, meteor

Is there a onConnection hook for client side on Meteor?   This is my issue:
Im trying to detect anytime Meteor reconnects to server to programmatically resubscribe to some data based on a parameter.

Meteor actually resubscribe automatically to my default subscriptions, but I have also a globlal subscription based on a parameter, and it is not reloaded after reconnection:

```
Meteor.subscribe('Members', fnGetLastEvent());
```

Im trying to reload it on a Meteor reconnection hook, if it exist.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you just store your global subscription parameter in `Session` and use it in your subscription (your subscription needs to be wrapped in an `autorun`).  I'm pretty sure Meteor re-runs all reactive computations that depend on a reactive data source (e.g. `Session` for example) upon reconnect.  It's worth a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a direct answer for you, but here are a few things you can try to see if they are a fit for your specific use case.

1) Set your own `onReconnect` callback function on the client side.

```
Meteor.onReconnect = function() {
  console.log("meteor has reconnected);
  // do stuff
};
```

I tested this out from Chrome developer tools in the console of a Meteor app that I have.  I set the `onReconnect` callback, ran `Meteor.disconnect()`, then ran `Meteor.reconnect()` and my callback fired.  The only caveat is I'm not sure if this callback is run **after** the connection has been established or **before**.

2) Put your `subscribe` call inside of an `autorun` that uses `Meteor.status()` as a reactive data source.  I do a similar check in one of my apps to check if Meteor is not connected and then display a modal informing the user that their data is no longer real-time.  Here is the main logic that I use to detect when Meteor is disconnected vs. reconnected.

```
var updateCountdownTimeout;
var nextRetry = new ReactiveVar(0);

Tracker.autorun(() => {
  if (Meteor.status().status === 'waiting') {
    updateCountdownTimeout = Meteor.setInterval(() => {
      nextRetry.set(Math.round((Meteor.status().retryTime - (new Date()).getTime()) / 1000));
    }, 1000);
  } else {
    nextRetry.set(0);
    Meteor.clearInterval(updateCountdownTimeout);
  }

  if (!Meteor.status().connected && Meteor.status().status !== 'offline' && Meteor.status().retryCount > 0) {
    console.log("Connection to server has been LOST!");
  } else {
    console.log("Connection to server has been RESTORED!");
    // put subscription logic here
  }
});
```

The caveat here is I'm not sure what will happen the first time the app is loaded.  I'm not sure if your subscription logic will run or if it will only run after a reconnect going forward (you can test this out).

3) This one is just theoretical.  It seems like you ought to be able to store your subscription parameter in `Session` and put your subscription logic inside an `autorun`.  Upon reconnection, the `autorun` in theory should run again.  Assuming this is inside of a template somewhere, then it would look like this.

```
this.autorun(() => {
  this.subscribe('Members', Session.get('sub_params'));
});
```

4) There are some callbacks you can setup on the [client `Meteor.connection._stream` object](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/ddp-client/livedata_connection.js#L380) that you could potentially use.  The options available are on `message`, `reset`, and `disconnect`.  I have used a callback on `message` for debugging before (see below).

```
Meteor.connection._stream.on('message', function (message) {
  console.log("receive", JSON.parse(message));
});
```

Assuming on `reset` is fired when a connection is re-established, then you might be able to put your subscription logic there.

```
Meteor.connection._stream.on('reset', function () {
  // subscription logic here
});
```

Good luck!

Comment: You did it again @jordanwillis!  I tried your option No. 4 and it is working now, thank you!  Here is my code (I only resubscribe if I'm in a specific route when the reconnection happens, otherwise I resubscribe when switching routes):

   `Meteor.connection._stream.on('reset', function () {  
  if (Router.current().route.getName() == "eventContainer.:_id") {
    alert ("Reconnected.  Ready to subscribe to:"+Router.current().params._id );
    Meteor.subscribe('Members', Router.current().params._id);
  }
});`

Comment: Any idea for this @jordanwillis?  =) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43241937/publication-receiving-parameter-for-slice-not-refreshing?noredirect=1#comment73592669_43241937

Comment: Take a look at my submitted answer on that question.