# Subscription not updated when collection subfield changes in publication (using $slice)

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a publication which receives a parameter from a subscription to determine how many records to return from an array inside a collection (Using $slice).  The issue I have is that my data is not refreshed on my template when a new parameter is sent through the subscription.  This is my code:

Publication:

```
Meteor.publish('Conversations', function (record_limit) {
  var bunchsize = 50;
  var multiplier = 1;
  if (record_limit) {
    multiplier = record_limit;
  } 
  var publimit = bunchsize * multiplier;
  return Conversations.find({users:{$in:[this.userId]}},{fields:{"lstmsg":1,  "msg":{"$slice":-publimit}}});        
});
```

Trigger to load more array objects:

```
var convCounter = 1;
Template.conversation.events({
  'click .js-loadmore': function() {
    convCounter = convCounter + 1;
    Deps.autorun(function() { Meteor.subscribe("Conversations",convCounter); });
  }
});
```

Any advice why the subscription is not being refreshed on my template?  It always shows only 50 items for "msg" field while it has more than 200 items on it.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that `return Conversations.find({users:{$in:[this.userId]}},{fields:{"lstmsg":1,  "msg":{"$slice":-publimit}}})` should be `return Conversations.find({ users: { $in: this.userId }}, { fields: { lstmsg: 1,  msg: 1 }, $slice: -publimit })`

Comment: I tried this but now the result not event take into account the $slice command (Maybe because is not specified to which field it would apply).  In my original code posted the $slice is actually working but only for the first time the subscription is served, returning only the last 10 objects inside msg array.  Maybe you are thinking on "$limit"

Comment: Ah, actually I was thinking of `$skip` - I missed that the `msg` key contained an array. The Meteor docs don't mention `$slice` at all although it is of course a mongodb projection.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `ReactiveVar` instead and wrapping your subscription in an `autorun` inside your Template's `onCreated` callback.

```
Template.conversation.onCreated(function() {
  this.convCounter = new ReactiveVar(1);

  this.autorun(() => {
    this.subscribe('Conversations', this.convCounter.get());
  });
});

Template.conversation.events({
  'click .js-loadmore': function(event, instance) {
    instance.convCounter.set(instance.convCounter.get() + 1);
  }
});
```

As you process your click event it will update the `ReactiveVar` which will then in tern cause the previous publication to stop and start a new one (with your new `$slice` value).

You will also have to modify your publication and use the lower level api in order to trick mergebox to send down sub-field changes to the client (otherwise, if you re-subscribe with a new `record_limit` value the client record will not get updated with the `msg` sub-field values).  Note, this approach is only viable if the subscribing client uses the data in a "read only" fashion because we modify the `_id` field being sent down in order to trick mergebox.

```
Meteor.publish('Conversations', function (record_limit) {
  var bunchsize = 50;
  var multiplier = 1;
  if (record_limit) {
    multiplier = record_limit;
  } 
  var publimit = bunchsize * multiplier;

  const handle = Conversations.find({
    users: {
      $in: [this.userId]
    }
  }, {
    fields: {
      "lstmsg": 1, "msg": {
        "$slice": -publimit
      }
    }
  }).observe({
    added: (doc) => {
      this.added("Conversations", doc._id + publimit, doc);
    },
    changed: (newDoc, oldDoc) => {
      this.changed("Conversations", newDoc._id + publimit, newDoc);
    },
    removed: (oldDoc) => {
      this.removed("Conversations", oldDoc._id + publimit);
    },
  });

  this.ready();

  this.onStop(() => {
    handle.stop();
  });  
});
```

The theory is that upon re-subscription with a new `record_limit` argument, any data previously loaded on the client (from a previous subscription) will be thrown away and replaced with the new data because the doc `_id` field is different (since we have used the `record_limit` as part of the id).

Comment: I tried it but the subscription still not refreshing.  I tried changing the $slice for $limit and then the automatic refresh works, sadly that doesn't retrieve the data I need. It seems the issue is updating when $slice is used.

Comment: What do you mean changed `$slice` to `$limit`?

Comment: I'm using $slice to return only the last 25 records inside the "msg" field, which is an array.  In the other hand if I change the query to use $limit (query syntax change as well) it returns the last 25 records from my collection.  When I change the $limit value dynamically the subscription refresh automatically.

Comment: Ok got it.  Meteor is good about not stopping/starting a subscription if nothing has changes about the actual query.  Since Meteor only expects to find 1 or 0 in the `fields` modifier, I'm guessing that it doesn't realize something has actually changed so it's not actually stopping the prev subscription.  I think you are going to have to force it.  Let me show you how.

Comment: @Ruben Just out of curiosity, have you put a `console.log` inside your publication function to see if it does actually get called each time the `convCounter` changes?  If not, I would do that and report back your results.

Comment: Yes I did, and the publication is being called.  The parameter for $slice is also changing anytime it is called.  I also have confirmed the field has more objects than the specified in $slice.

Comment: Ok, that's good to know. Have you tried logging the `msg` field to the console too to make sure it's correct to? I'm assuming it will print different​ values like you are wanting.

Comment: I did it just now.  I sent to the server console the returned value from the publication and it shows the increments in `$slice`.  Doing the same on the client (browser console) it doesn't shows the increments in `$slice`.

Comment: See if the new publish function in my answer gets past the mergebox sub-field merge constraint for this specific case.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround idea.  Since I'm using groundDb I'm not sure if this workaround will increase constantly my offline database size with duplicate data, since the old _ids won't be deleted.

Comment: Hmm...I have never heard of groundDb so I'm not sure.  Based on their [documentation](https://github.com/GroundMeteor/db#limiting-the-stored-data) you should be able to easily clean it up on the client side if needed.  However, its worth testing to see if it already cleans it up automatically if you are using it to `observeSource` of the parallel `minimongo` collection.

Comment: Mmmm... Just seeing your suggestion of concatening _id + publimit... Let me check it.

Comment: Also, for this publication, you could even publish to a different client collection used only for this specific use case so that you can easily destroy the data when you are done with it.  To do that just change the name of the first arg in `this.added`, `this.changed`, and `this.removed` and create a local collection of the same name (whatever you change it to)

Comment: I found a solution @jordanwillis, using `stop` subscription and then resubscribing.  Thanks for your help and food for mind.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Meteor doesn't refresh subscriptions when a change happens in a subfield level (Such as in my case, inside msg) as is stated in the documentation:

> Currently, when multiple subscriptions publish the same document only
>   the top level fields are compared during the merge. This means that if
>   the documents include different sub-fields of the same top level
>   field, not all of them will be available on the client. We hope to
>   lift this restriction in a future release.

Check the issue thread:
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3764#issuecomment-75853901

Issue is still open... big turn around.

**WORKAROUND:** The way I found to make it works was to stop the previous subscription each time I need to retrieve more fields from array through the $slice parameter, like this:

```
lastSub = "";
convCounter = 1;
Template.conversation.onCreated(function() {
   lastSub = Meteor.subscribe("Conversation", convCounter);
});

Template.conversation.events({
  'click .js-loadmore': function() {
     convCounter = convCounter + 1; 
     if (lastSub) {lastSub.stop();}
        lastSub = Meteor.subscribe("Conversation", convCounter);
  }   
});
```

The workaround could be inefficient for data access but I expect my users won't surf old conversations so often.

Comment: You should still be able to work around that restriction though.  Let me update my answer with an example for you to try.